# Hover doesn't affect nested elements

Tags: html, css, hover, less

I'm trying to code a simple navigation bar with Less:

```
.navbody {
        display:table-cell;
        padding-left:20px;
        ul {
            .clearMP;
            li {
                .clearMP;
                display:table-cell;
                height:@navheight;
                vertical-align:middle;
                &:hover {
                    background-color:darken(#fafafa,30%);
                    cursor:pointer;
                    a {
                        color:white;
                        border:1px solid black;
                    }
                }
                a {
                    display:block;
                    &:link,&:visited {
                        font-size:15px;
                        color:black;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        padding:0 10px;
                    }
                    &:hover,&:active {
                        color:white;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class='navbody'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Documention</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do that when li element is hovered, the a color will change to white. I tried the 
`li:hover a` method but it doesn't work. 
I now learned that only `color:white` doesn't work, but if i try change the border it does work.

Comment: What does the resulting CSS look like?

Comment: The "color:white" property works see : http://jsbin.com/tuvun/2/edit

Comment: What other CSS files do you have included? What do you see when you do `inspect element` in chrome?